# proof by finding suitable instances and resolution

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, proof-theory

I am trying to proof by resolution the following:

1) Given a language with the binary relation symbols $<, <<, <<<$ and the binary function symbols $+, *$ and the constant symbols a, b,
proof by resolution that the following CNF is unsatisfiable:
$\{\{a+b < a*b\}; \{x_2 \not< y_2, x_2 + y_2 << x_2 * y_2\}; \{x_2 \not<< y_2, x_2 + y_2 <<< x_2 * y_2\}; \{x \not<<< y\}\}$

Hint: Find a set of instances without free variables of this clauses, that are propositionally unsatisfiable.

I don't manage to find suitable instances of the clauses. Do you have any idea?

2) Name a set of n clauses (with O(n) symbols) that is unsatisfiable, but whereby the smallest set of instances without free variables, that are propositionally unsatisfiable, does have more than O(n) symbols.

I have no idea how such a set of clauses could look like. Hopefully it becomes more clear, when 1) is solved?

I'd appreciate your help on this! :)

Comment: If anything is unclear in my post, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> proof by resolution that the following CNF is unsatisfiable:
>   $\{\{a+b < a*b\}; \{x_2 \not< y_2, x_2 + y_2 \ll x_2 * y_2\}; \{x_2 \not\ll y_2, x_2 + y_2 \lll x_2 * y_2\}; \{x \not\lll y\}\}$

You need to use $a+b < a*b$ in some other clause. The operator "$<$" only occurs in $x_2 \not< y_2$ so you should take $x_2=a+b, y_2=a*b$. The other instantiations follow the same reasoning. So you end up with clauses,

\begin{align*} 
& a+b < a*b\\\\
& a+b \not< a*b\\
&   (a+b) + (a*b) \ll (a+b) * (a*b)\\\\
& (a+b) + (a*b) \not\ll (a+b) * (a*b)\\
&    ((a+b)+(a*b))+((a+b)*(a*b)) \lll ((a+b)+(a*b))*((a+b)*(a*b))\\\\
&    ((a+b)+(a*b))+((a+b)*(a*b)) \not\lll ((a+b)+(a*b))*((a+b)*(a*b))\\\\
\end{align*}

Applying the resolution method is now trivial.

---

For question number 2 consider,

\begin{align*} 
 &\{a+b <_1 a*b\}\\
 %
 &\{x_k \not<_{(k-1)} y_k,\ x_k + y_k <_k x_k * y_k\}\quad 1<k<n\\
 &\{x_{n} \not<_{n-1}< y_{n}\}  
 \end{align*}

and to instantiate the free variables consider terms, 
 $s_0 = a$,
 $t_0 = b$,
 $s_k =s_{(k-1)}+t_{(k-1)}$ and
 $t_k =s_{(k-1)}*t_{(k-1)}$, 
and define substitutions $x_k/s_{k-1}$ and $y_k/t_{k-1}$ for $1<k<n$. The number of symbols grows exponentially with $k$ and therefore also with $n$.

Comment: Thank you! Your first, second, third and sixth line are clear to me. But how about the fourth and fifth line? I seems you substituted $x_2/(a+b)+(a*b)$ and $y_2/(a+b)*(a*b)$ there, but in the two clauses before it was $x_2 = a+b$ and $y_2 = a*b$. I think something like this is not allowed?

Comment: Oh I think I am wrong. We are allowed to make clauses variable disjunct, aren't we? Then we have $x_1$ and $y_1$ instead of $ $x_2, y_2$ in the third clause and we can substitute that for what you did above, right?

Comment: Indeed that's what I did. A set such as $\{x2≪̸y2,x2+y2⋘x2∗y2\}$ is typically a  a schema, that is  shorthand notation for a union $\bigcup\{\{x2≪̸y2,x2+y2⋘x2∗y2\} | x2, y2 \in \mathcal{D}\}$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is their domain.

Comment: That's the only way I can make sense of the question. Unless  if you meant to write  $x1≮y1,x1+y1\ll x1∗y1$ rather than $x2≮y2,x2+y2≪x2∗y2$ in the second set of your question. If you do that, then you have different variables to instantiate. Regardless each of those sets should have their variables instantiated with different values, that's the only way the question makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am quite sure now that you are absolutely right! 
Do you have any idea for 2), too?

Comment: For the second question you just have to generalise this example from 4 to $n$ clauses. In this example with each (instantiated) clause the number of symbol doubles.

Comment: edited with some detail on question 2

Comment: Great and thanks for the explanation! (I think you meant 1 < k < n instead of 1 < k < n-1?)
But what about the smallest set of instances without free variables, that are propositionally unsatisfiable, which has to have more than O(n) symbols? Am I right that the clauses you gave are the n clauses that are unsatisfiable, but that this is the case, we only see by building their set of instances without free variables, which turns out to be propositionally unsatisfiable and has $O(n^2)$ symbols?

Comment: Yes, should be $n$. And yes that's it from the clauses with $O(n)$ symbols you get via substitutions the clauses with no free variables and $O(2^n)$ symbols (note it is exponential, not just polynomial).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! :)